# Is there a circuit that amplifies current or voltage relative to signal frequency?

Tags: audio, design

I am trying to create a circuit that outputs a higher voltage/current as the frequency of the signal input (such as an audio input) gets higher - such as to allow all frequencies to bypass a capacitor with a certain value. I have a design already, but I am not sure if it would work for this purpose, or at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDQer0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Search for "differentiator circuit".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean, but there are frequency to voltage converters, tachometers, all kind of conversion circuits.

Comment: I know what a tachometer is, but I want something without a micro-controller, with as few parts as possible, and could be easily built by someone with only a moderate-high (around 80%) understanding of electrical engineering.

Comment: 80% is great. After ten years in this industry, my understanding hopefully is greater than 10%. Anyway, i googled "frequency to voltage converter" and several Integrated components arised.

Comment: I finally pulled a circuit off the internet, which is a simple tachometer circuit. Here's the link: http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/tachometer-circuit.png. If it actually works, it could be adapted to my needs, by feeding off a small amount of the AC signal to an amplifier which would have a DC source coming from the tachometer. Also, when I meant 80%, I meant as the mathematics and theory goes; when it comes to actually designing circuits, everything becomes useless and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to rectify the signal I don't think the circuit you provided will work.
The simulation shows that the transistors only turn on during the negative half of the signal.

To pass all signals above a certain frequency you really need is a high pass filter.

In it can be made from just one resistor and capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1qTk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The signal comes in one side of a blocking capacitor.  The other side of the capacitor has a pulldown resistor to 0V.  The output is on the side of the capacitor oposite the input.

The cutoff frequency is 1/(2 * pi * R * C) for that configuration.

The transfer function is...
Vout/Vin = R/(R + 1/(2 * pi * i * f *  C))
where "i" is the imaginary number sqrt(-1)
Vin is the input signal
Vout is the output signal
f is the frequency in Hz
R is the resistane in ohms
C is the capacitance in Farads

The magnitude of the transfer function is...
|Vout/Vin| = R/ sqrt(R^2 + 1/(2 * pi * f * C)^2)

You can create higher order filters by cascading multiple stages (and optionally using an op-amp) to get a sharper cutoff.

You may notice that the high pass filter has a gain of 0 at 0Hz and a gain of 1 at very high frequency.  If you need a gain of more than 1 you can feed the output of the filter into a standard common-emitter or op-amp type amplifier circuit.

Comment: No, I do not mean signals above a certain frequency. I mean something that lowers the signal intensity for lower frequencies, so that all frequencies will bypass a capacitor. My theory was based upon the equivalence of the Farad, A*S/V. As the frequency increases, the S decreases, so I want the A to increase so the capacitance of that is the same. Also, I do not care about the rectification, I could just put a diode facing the opposite direction of the current flow, so that it will bypass everything while on the positive half.

Comment: A high pass filter, as I described, does lower the signal output voltage for lower frequencies, and raise it for higher frequencies.

Comment: Are you trying to create a device that outputs a DC voltage that is proportional to frequency?  Like a frequency to voltage converter?  Or are you trying to make a circuit that passes an alternating signal through, with the output intensity based on frequency?

Comment: The ladder option.